# Shopping Cart in every page optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, optimization

I have a MVC5 project written in C# with shopping cart feature, I store all cart details in the database so everytime a user browse a page it will show how many items is currently in the cart. For example if a user add product A and B in his cart, then it will show "CART(2)" in top right corner. I get this number by calling the database in every page but this seems like a waste to me.

So far I don't have a problem in the database but that is because the site is still new, I'm afraid this will become a problem later. Is this a normal approach for shopping cart or is there any other way?

Any help will be appreciated and apologize for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without a caching strategy in place, this is really the only reliable method of doing this.

You could cache the database calls, so that every subsequent request to the page will display the cached version of the shopping cart data. However, you would need to make sure that the cart object is removed from the cache each time the user updates the items in their carts (add, remove, qty etc.), so that the page will request the latest version of the DB instead of the cache.

Caching the results from the DB will have to effect of reducing the load on the database server and response times as there will be far fewer calls to update the cart than there will be to get the cart on every page view. The flip side of this is that it introduces an amount of complexity into the system which can/will effect testing etc. You would need to determine if the additional complexity is worth it. Personally, I would make the call that the small amount of complexity is worth it.

I would also steer away from things like using cookies to store the cart data as cookies should be treated as volatile as the user can remove/disable them at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Juzzbott and using cookies is not the best option here , for many reasons. Another option is to use `session states`, but i am not a big fan of that as well as it is stored in-memory by default, which is not a flexible option if you need to remember data for your users.

One option is to use `.Net caching`  it's been there since *version 1.1* and it's not very hard to it setup a basic scenario [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.71).aspx) for more info.

Of course you can check other libraries and some of them and open source. at work we use [`redis`](http://redis.io/) which works great for us.

Comment: Session state would already be *per user*, caching would need more work to make it per user, so why use it for such a simple thing as per user data storage? And why would caching data in memory be a bad thing? Simple cart count/price, even for 10000 concurrent users the memory usage is very small.

Comment: Session state in memory can be bad for the same reasons as cookies. It's volatile. Each time the app pool is recycled you loose all your session data. This doesn't exist if your using SQL server as your session state persistence, or State Server, but these are not the default have their own considerations.